# How Can This Address Hold So Much Data?

Tags: memory, gdb

Not sure if this is a blatantly terrible misunderstanding, but I've been having so trouble with inspecting memory.  Here's the following from gdb from examining with `x/8w`.

```
0xbffff7a0: 0xb7f9f729 0xb7fd6ff4 0xbffff7d8 0x08048529
0xbffff7b0: 0xb7fd6ff4 0xbffff870 0xbffff7d8 0x00000000
```

So I'm assuming that `0xb7f9f729` is at `0xbffff7a0`, then `0xb7fd6ff4` is at `0xbffff7a4`, etc.  Could you explain how this works byte wise?  Is that 16 bytes from the first memory portion to the next, and each 4 bytes holds it's own word?

I'm having a hard time grasping this memory concept, anyone know a good resource that makes learning it easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and yes to both questions.

`gdb(1)` understands `w` modifier in your `x/8w` command as "four byte words", so you are printing 32 bytes in groups of four. `gdb(1)` just lays them out in short lines with offsets for readability.

I should mention that the exact values printed actually depend on the [platform endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

You would get similar but probably more understandable layout with `x/32`.

It's all in [`the fine manual`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory.html).